# Transpose arrays in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, transpose

In BigQuery, how could I transpose these records:

```
 fruit  | color  |  aA        |  aB        |  aC
--------+--------+------------+------------+------------
 apple  | green  | [10,11]    | [12,13]    | [14,15]
 orange | orange | [20,21,22] | [23,24,25] | [26,27,28]
```

to:

```
 fruit  | color  | A  | B  | C
--------+--------+----+----+----
 apple  | green  | 10 | 12 | 14
 apple  | green  | 11 | 13 | 15
 orange | orange | 20 | 23 | 26
 orange | orange | 21 | 24 | 27
 orange | orange | 22 | 25 | 28
```

In PrestoDB/Athena or PostgreSQL, I would use UNNEST with multiple parameters, but it is not supported by BigQuery.

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(aA, aB, aC) AS t(A, B, C)
```

Note that:

- all arrays in one row have the same length;
- the length of the arrays can be different between records.

---

The scratchpad:

```
#standardSQL

WITH arrays AS (
  SELECT 'apple' AS fruit, 'green' AS color, [10,11] AS aA, [12,13] AS aB, [14,15] AS aC UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange' AS fruit, 'orange' AS color, [20,21,22] AS aA, [23,24,25] AS aB, [26,27,28] AS aC

)
SELECT * FROM arrays
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WITH OFFSET on the first array and then the bracket operator on the other two:

```
#standardSQL
WITH arrays AS (
  SELECT 'apple' AS fruit, 'green' AS color, [10,11] AS aA, [12,13] AS aB, [14,15] AS aC UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange' AS fruit, 'orange' AS color, [20,21,22] AS aA, [23,24,25] AS aB, [26,27,28] AS aC
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(aA, aB, aC),
  aB[OFFSET(off)] AS B, aC[OFFSET(off)] AS C
FROM arrays
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(aA) AS A WITH OFFSET off;
```

I have passed along feedback to our technical writers to make this syntax easier to find and to provide an example as well.

Comment: Thanks ! A small fix is needed for your query to complete: `SELECT * EXCEPT(aA, aB, aC, A)`. I completely overlooked the `WITH OFFSET` clause in the [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) doc. I think this use case would perfectly fit in [Working with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays).

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'll try to follow up here once we've updated the docs. Thanks!